# UNITY | Update or InvokeRepeating?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use many timers in my Unity project, they done like this:

```
void Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if(timer < 0)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

And in every google link they looks like this.
But today i found (im newbie) `InvokeRepeating();` method.

So here is updated timer

```
int timer = 60; 

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("Timer", 1f, 1f);
}

void Timer()
{
    timer -= 1;
}
```

So why people change timers in `Update()`?

And which method less inpact on performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends!

As usual in programming there are most of the time multiple valid solutions for a problem.

In my eyes the bigest difference is that `InvokeRepeating` is also working on **inactive** GameObjects or **disabled** Components while `Update` is only called while the object is active and the component enabled.

---

Note, however, that your current examples do different things. To make them equivalent it should look like either

```c#
void Start()
{
    timer = 1f;
}

void Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if(timer < 0)
    {
        timer = 1f;
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

or

```c#
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(DoSomething), 1f, 1f);
}
```

Btw: A third basically equivalent solution would be a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) (which is basically a temporary `Update` method - in fact the `MoveNext` call gets executed right after the `Update` would)

```c#
// Yes, Start can be an IEnumertaor and is in this case internally implicitly started as Coroutine!
IEnumerator Start() 
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        DoSeomthing();
    }
}
```

---

As mentioned by Kuruchy: There is also a difference in behavior related to the [`timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html).

- `Update`: since it uses Time.deltaTime to decrease the timer it will be affected by the time scale

  → in order to avoid this you would need to use [`Time.unscaledDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledDeltaTime.html) instead. **But** afaik still if setting `Time.timeScale = 0;` then `Update` isn't called at all.
- Coroutine: Similar to update the [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) is also timeScale dependent.

  → in roder to avoid this you would need to use [`WaitForSecondsRealitme`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) **but** afaik even then setting `Time.timeScale = 0;` would lead to the routine not getting called at all.
- `InvokeRepeating`: Fromt he docs I can only see that

  > This does not work if you set the time scale to 0.

  not sure how it reacts to the timescale though but I would actually guess the same. Though, here there is no real work around like for the other two.

---

Performance wise you most probably don't even have to care! I guess it would be over-optimizing.

However my guess would be that `Update` is actually slightly faster since there you already know the method reference while when using `InvokeRepeating` you are passing it as a `string` which is additionally error prone and means that internally Unity has to find that method first.

Comment: You could also add another reason to your explanation. The first case, the one using deltaTime, is time dependent, and the other ones are not. That means that if the user changes the timeScale from 1 to 0 or 2 or any other number, this is the only solution that will change the velocity it runs.

Comment: Yeah most important difference here is that one runs every update and one runs at an interval and these are not equal. I'd also imagine that the method name is resolved at startup and execution is as fast as calling the method directly (it probably just uses reflection to get a `MethodInfo` object to execute against)

Comment: @Kuruchy - InvokeRepeating and WaitForSeconds is also depended on timeScale. You need to use realtimeSinceStartup inside a while loop if you want to measure time not dependent on timeScale.

Comment: InvokeRepeating is likely using reflection to find and trigger the method and then use an internal clock and limited to no parameter. It probably also generates a bit of garbage, same with the coroutine example creating a new WaitForSeconds object (this can be prevented with reusing the same object). Update is most likely optimized. The reason why one or the other  should be more about the expectation, coroutine for a temporary update, Invoke and InvokeRepeating are limited to usage, I actually rarely use it but it is entirely personal. Update for all other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into too much detail is because of the performance.

The Update() method is invoked internally by Unity and they've done a pretty good job in optimizing it.

InvokeRepeating is much slower in comparison. First of all because the initial method invocation is using the Reflection to find the method you want to start and it's respective calls also take more time than Update. And you want to avoid using Reflection in your code as much as possible.

Here is nice, short article in which the tests were performed between these two methods - http://www.kittehface.com/2017/09/unity-performance-with-invokerepeating.html